# Using Name (Auto Number) as Key to Map

Tags: apex

Is it possible to build a map where the key is the "Name" field of the object itself.

For example like

`Map<Name, String> m = new Map<Name,String>();`

In my case the `Name` field is an auto number.

Also can someone tell me what is the data type of the `Name` field in general ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Name` field is of type `String`. If you lookup the fields on the SObject you will be able to see the Data Type. The screenshot below shows the Name field for the Asset object.

[image]

Your `Map` would be something like this:

```
Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>();
```

and here is an example of how to use it:

```
m.put(so.Name, 'Here is my value');
String theValue = m.get(so.Name);
```

See [Map Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) for more detail on using a `Map`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it but I think you can build a map where the autonumber is the key of the object but you would need to change it to something like this

**Example**:

```
map<String,Case> themap=new Map<String,Case>();
```

Then you could do something like :

```
for(Case c:[Select CaseNumber FROM Case])
{
     themap.put(c.CaseNumber,c);
}
```